# Can VBA range selection work with a dynamic range (determined by strings)?

Tags: vba, excel

If I do `Range("PolicyYearDRS_2").Select`, it returns the result just fine.

If I do

```
For n = 1 to 10
Range("PolicyYearDRS_" & n).Select
```

it doesn't work.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Please explain how it didn't work?  Did it not behave as expected or did it raise an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the solution is to make n a string

so this works:

```
For n = 1 to 10
Range("PolicyYearDRS_" & Cstr(n)).Select
Next
```

Comment: `n` should be implicitly converted from int to string by the concatenation operator `&`.  Using `Cstr` shouldn't be necessary.